# How to calucate the sum through VBA in excel based on variable column?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file where the tables is generated through macro script something like this.

**Type Cost**
Indirect 44
Direct 68
Direct 33
Indirect 120

I want to generate sum of all the indirect and direct cost separately in two different columnn.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve] to help write a question in line with the site's guidelines. We'd love to help but need to see what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: `SUMIFS()`. That's all you should need, assuming those are two separate columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the worksheet, use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A5="Indirect")*(B2:B5))
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A5="Direct")*(B2:B5))
```

[image]

So with VBA:

```
Sub Equivalent()
    x = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT((A2:A5=""Indirect"")*(B2:B5))")
    y = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT((A2:A5=""Direct"")*(B2:B5))")
End Sub
```

**Note:**

In VBA we double-up the double quotes.

Comment: thanks I tried sumif as mentioned above but it didn't work. This one worked like charm. Thanks again.